De donde obtengo el archivo normalizer.exe que deberia estar en la ruta c:\python312\scripts
tengo que correr un proyecto que recibi y no me figura instalado el archivo normalizer.exe,  de que paquete o librería lo tengo que instalar?

Hola Eduardo, bienvenido, dudo mucho que alguien te pueda contestar con tan poca "data", te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y agregues una descrpción suscinta de lo que el código hace, y la porción del mismo, en donde se invoca a normalizer.

Normalmente el script normalizer (.../bin/normalizer en Linux y .../scripts/normalizer.exe en Windows) pertenece al paquete charset-normalizer y permite su uso a través de CLI.
Simplemente instala el paquete a través de pip:
py -3.12 -m pip install charset-normalizer

y deberías tener normalizer.exe.
En realidad es solo la opción más probable, es un paquete bastante popular y dependencia común de muchos otros (reflex, requests, ...), pero nada impide que otro paquete random instale también su propio normalizer.exe y que sea la dependencia real de tu proyecto. En cualquier caso, el proyecto debería manejar adecuadamente sus dependencias o al menos listarlas explícitamente.
